# Pact CDC: Cleaning up older consumer and provider version from Broker periodically

Tags: testing, pact, contract, pact-broker

I have set up a pack broker locally and ran few iterations of consumer and provider.
The list of verified pact over few days has gone to 100 now.

I am looking for options to clear the contracts and the verification results which are older than 15 days.

Is there a way of bulk cleaning the contracts? Can this be set up like a cron job in the Broker?

Can we set a retention period for the contracts and verification results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can now do exactly that - see https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact_broker/issues/360